# OnViewLoaded in caliburn is called only once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn

I have task list with several screens.
If I open screen number 1, switch to screen number 2 and then back to screen number1.
OnViewLoaded will not be called in the second time I open screen number1

Any Ideas why it happened?

Comment: OnViewLoaded is only called when your view is loaded (the first time) in memory. So just only one event OnViewLoaded. If you want to trap if the window is in front, you could test if the window has the focus (for example).

Comment: We make effort to answer........

Answer (score 0):

OnViewLoaded is only called when your view is loaded (the first time) in memory.

read in caliburn documentation:

OnViewLoaded – Since Screen implements IViewAware, it takes this as an opportunity to let you know when your view’s Loaded event is fired. Use this if you are following a SupervisingController or PassiveView style and you need to work with the view. This is also a place to put view model logic which may be dependent on the presence of a view even though you may not be working with the view directly.